# Glassfish 3.1.1 Client session control

Tags: java, http, session, glassfish-3

I'm having a little problem with Glassfish when trying to have some control over the httpsession created everytime a client access a web application i'm running. Thing is I want some temporary files to be created on the server side that will only last while the client is connected and be deleted from disk when client disconnects.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem..? are in trouble in creating the temp files..?

Comment: Problem is im still quite new to server programming and i dont know how server gets a notice when a client disconnects/closes browser :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class which implements [`HttpSessionListner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) interface and, implement [`sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionCreated%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) and [`sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent%29) methods. Those methods will be called, or simply your implemented class will be notified when there is a session created or destroyed in the application. You can use these two methods to do your work. And, you don't need to worry about client disconnected or close the browser, contained will do it for you.

You can get the session from [HttpSessionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html)'s [getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html#getSession%28%29) method. Then create or delete files for that session/user.